# @Material ui Autocomplete is it possible to show a custom label in getOptionLabel just like in renderOption?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have requrirment to show the total number of items in each option for Automplete. While I am able to show in expanded items I cant show when one is selected .. refer to the image and code and suggest me how to achieve the same in selected state like renderOption.
[image: see the current state]

```
 getOptionLabel={option =>
                    `${option.listName} (${
                      option.contacts ? option.contacts.length : 0
                    })`
                  }
                  renderOption={option => (
                    <>
                      <div
                        style={{
                          display: 'flex',
                          width: '160px',
                          overflow: 'hidden',
                          justifyContent: 'space-between'
                        }}
                      >
                        <div style={{ width: '160px', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                          {option.listName}
                        </div>

                        <div className={classes.listCount}>
                          {option.contacts
                            ? option.contacts.length
                            : contactLists.length}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the `renderInput` property where you can customize the output of the component.
in it you can return a `TextField` which has a `label` property.

to customize the label you basicaly need to give it a `className`. To do so assign to the `TextField` a `InputLabelProps` property that accepts object of the label props like that `InputLabelProps={{ className: "autocompleteLabel" }}`

example:

```js
<Autocomplete
       ...
        renderInput={(params) => {
          return (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={"choose " + resource}
              InputLabelProps={{ className: "autocompleteLabel" }}
              InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
```

now if you inspect the autocomplete component you'll find the class assigned to the label
[image]

now that label is assigned with a class, you can do normal css